# How to only output the header when building a client side http downloader

Tags: c, networking, network-programming

I am building a client side HTTP web downloader.

I have been able to successfully receive a reply/data from the server using this line:

```
char serverreply[4096];
int x = recv(sockfd, serverreply ,MAXLINE,0);
```

With this line, it sends out get request. The output is below. The header is up till **connection close**.

It ends with a unique `\r\n\r\n`.

With that, how can I only output everything before `<!doctype html>` to the terminal?

Thank you

````
Path:index.html, port: 80, Ipaddress 93.184.216.34 The message was sent
File was opened
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Age: 27639
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Fri, 14 Jan 2022 06:16:48 GMT
Etag: "3147526947"
Expires: Fri, 21 Jan 2022 06:16:48 GMT
Last-Modified: Thu, 17 Oct 2019 07:18:26 GMT
Server: ECS (oxr/8321)
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Cache: HIT
Content-Length: 1256
Connection: close

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example Domain</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-color: #f0f0f2;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: -apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        
    }



 here is my while 1 loop.   ```while (1){

        int x = recv(sockfd, serverreply ,MAXLINE,0);
        if (x <0){
            printf("\nError generated by socket layer: %d", errno);
        }else{
            if (x>0){
              if (argc ==4){
                  if(strcmp(forh,"-h")==0){
                    //this is where i need to only print the header 

                    break;
                  }
            }
````

Answer (score 0):

Keep reading until you find a `\r\n\r\n` in the buffer of the connection closes. When you find a `\r\n\r\n`, output everything up to that.

If you don't have `memmem`, it may be worth implementing it. It's a bit tedious to use `strstr` in an application like this.

Comment: What function would i use. I have tried using strstr, and it ends up printing everything but the header

Comment: You can use `strstr`, but it's tedious. It's much easier to use `memmem`. If your platform doesn't have it, you can easily find an implementation. Post your full code (include the loop that keeps reading until you have the entire header). The pain with `strstr` is you have to keep putting a zero byte on the end of your partial message and it breaks if there's a zero byte received over the connection.

Comment: ahh i will post it above. Please take a look

Comment: Your code will mishandle the case where one call to `recv` gets the first `\r` and then the next call to `recv` gets the `\n\r\n`. You probably should accumulate all the data in a single buffer, appending each call to `recv` to the end of the previous one.

Comment: A bit confused, because the recv works perfectly fine when doing an output of the body only to a file. And to identify the end of the header, im using strstr (, "\r\n\r\n").

Comment: What are you confused by? Do you understand that the `recv` call has no idea where the request ends and just gives you as much data as it happens to have (up to the limit you specified) when you called it?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> int x = recv(sockfd, serverreply ,MAXLINE,0);
> ```
>
> It ends with a unique `\r\n\r\n`.
>
> With that, how can I only output everything before `<!doctype html>` to the terminal?

I have already been in the same situation multiple times and I typically used the following method to detect the `\r\n\r\n` sequence:

```
int state = 0;
...
for(/* each character received do ... */ ...)
{
    if(character == '\r' && state == 2) state = 3;
    else if(character == '\r') state = 1;
    else if(character == '\n' && state == 1) state = 2;
    else if(character == '\n' && state == 3)
    {
        /* "\r\n\r\n" has been received */
        state = 4;
        putchar('\n');
        ...
        break;
    }
    else state = 0;

    /* Print the character to the console */
    putchar(character);
}
```

This method has the following advantage:

Depending on the TCP connection (MTU, speed ...), `recv()` might return less data than `MAXLINE` bytes although there is still more data coming.

This means you have to call `recv()` multiple times until `recv()` returns zero or a negative value.

It might happen that the first call of `recv()` returns `HTTP/1.0 ... close\r\n` and the second call returns `\r\n<!doctype ...`.

In this situation, the array `serverreply[]` does not contain the whole sequence `\r\n\r\n` so searching for that sequence in the array (e.g. using `memmem()`) will not work.

Using my method, you set the variable `state` to zero before the first `recv()` and you don't  change the value of `state` when `recv()` is called again.

For this reason, the method will also detect the `\r\n\r\n` if it is "split" over multiple `recv()` calls.

**Edit**

More detailed example:

```
char state = 0;
char character;
int index;
int length;
char serverreply[MAXLINE];

do {
    length = recv(sockfd, serverreply, MAXLINE, 0);
    for(index = 0; index < length; index++)
    {
        character = serverreply[index];
        if(state >= 4)
        {
            /* Character belongs to the data */
        }
        else
        {
            putchar(character);
            if(character == '\r' && state == 2) state = 3;
            else if(character == '\r') state = 1;
            else if(character == '\n' && state == 1) state = 2;
            else if(character == '\n' && state == 3) state = 4;
            else state = 0;
        }
    }
} while(length > 0);
```

Comment: using this method, am i able to identify where the header has ended and only print that onto the terminal ?

Comment: @Lostttt Sure. As soon as you get into the `else if(character == '\n' && state == 3)` part, the header has finished. I added the line `state = 4` in my code: As soon as `state` has the value 4, the header is finished.

Comment: I see, does this look correct.                      `for ( char character = 0; character < serverreply;character++){
                  if(character == '\r' && state == 2) state = 3;
                    else if(character == '\r') state = 1;
                    else if(character == '\n' && state == 1) state = 2;
                  else if(character == '\n' && state == 3)
                      {
        /* "\r\n\r\n" has been received */
          putchar('\n');
          state = 4;
               break;
               }
    else state = 0;


    putchar(character);
}`

Comment: `!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~` its printing that as an output

Comment: @Lostttt That was not correct. Please see the example in my "edit" section.